# How do I round the milliseconds to seconds of timestamp in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to remove the millisecond off my timestamp and in doing so, rounding the value.

````
From this: 2019-11-11 19:10:57.981 UTC
To this: 2019-11-11 19:10:58 UTC```

Yes, I want the second rounded when truncated.
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_ADD(ingest_time, INTERVAL 500 MILLISECOND), SECOND)
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-11-11 19:10:57.981 UTC' ingest_time UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-11-11 19:10:57.381 UTC'
)
SELECT TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_ADD(ingest_time, INTERVAL 500 MILLISECOND), SECOND)
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row f0_  
1   2019-11-11 19:10:58 UTC  
2   2019-11-11 19:10:57 UTC
```

Comment: HI Mikhail, I don't understand your answer. My column for the timestamp is called ingest_time, would you be able to show me with ingest_time - not sure where to input it.